# Best way of doing lists that can be indexed efficiently in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection with documents that can either look like this (option A):

```
{
  "my_list": [
    { "id": "A", "other_data": 123 },
    { "id": "B", "other_data": 456 },
    { "id": "C", "other_data": 789 },
  ]
}
```

or like this (option B):

```
{
  "my_list": {
    "A": 123,
    "B": 456,
    "C": 789,
  }
}
```

Question is: **which one is more efficient for doing queries such as: *fetch me all documents that have id 'B' in 'my_list'*?**

Also, for the better option, how do you tell Mongo to create the relevant index?

Comment: Maybe this is not relevant, but I prefer *option B* because it looks simpler and it helps avoid duplicates in the data, but maybe it's much harder for the engine to run queries using "$exists"?

Comment: Also, and this should go without saying, the "my_list" could have _many_ records, and there could be _many_ documents in the collection.

Comment: Tecnically, `my_list` is not a list (:

Comment: I'm using the word "list" (which, as far as I know, doesn't really mean anything in Mongo) specifically to avoid giving the impression that I need this to be implemented with arrays or objects.

Comment: How many items (ids) are going to be in the `my_list`? Are you querying on the existence of the field "B" _or_ the value stored in it (`456`). For example, `if (B == 456) ...`, _or_ `if (B) ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Definitely the first one.

```
{
  "my_list": [
    { "id": "A", "other_data": 123 },
    { "id": "B", "other_data": 456 },
    { "id": "C", "other_data": 789 },
  ]
}
```

> MongoDB uses multikey indexes to index the content stored in arrays. If you index a field that holds an array value, MongoDB creates separate index entries for every element of the array. These multikey indexes allow queries to select documents that contain arrays by matching on element or elements of the arrays. MongoDB automatically determines whether to create a multikey index if the indexed field contains an array value; you do not need to explicitly specify the multikey type.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#multikey-index

The **second option** it's `object` type. You need to create `Single Field` or `Compound Index` to use indexes.

### Transform arrays into key:value store

MongoDB allows you to transform `Multikey Index array` as `key:value` store for during aggregation i.e.:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { "my_list.id" : "A" }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      my_list: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: "$my_list",
            in: {
              k: "$$this.id",
              v: "$$this.other_data"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If we take a look [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/explain/) command, MongoDB uses indexes for efficient execution of queries.

```
{
    "stages" : [ 
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {
                    "my_list.id" : "A"
                },
                "fields" : {
                    "my_list" : 1,
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "test.collection",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        "my_list.id" : {
                            "$eq" : "A"
                        }
                    },
                    "queryHash" : "599B2BF4",
                    "planCacheKey" : "48B2FCB0",
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "my_list.id" : 1.0
                            },
                            "indexName" : "my_list.id_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : true,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "my_list.id" : [ 
                                    "my_list"
                                ]
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "my_list.id" : [ 
                                    "[\"A\", \"A\"]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : []
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$project" : {
                "_id" : true,
                "my_list" : {
                    "$arrayToObject" : [ 
                        {
                            "$map" : {
                                "input" : "$my_list",
                                "as" : "this",
                                "in" : {
                                    "k" : "$$this.id",
                                    "v" : "$$this.other_data"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```